# Filtering combobox not working for common store combos

Tags: javascript, extjs, filter, combobox, store

I am using `ExtJS 2.3`. I have 3 comboboxes with following stores.
Here, combo2 and combo3 share same store.

Following are the combo stores-

**Combo1 Store:**
Vice President
Manager
Employee
Student

**Combo2 and Combo3 Store:**
Assignments
Meetings
Salary

Now my requirement is, if 'Student' is selected from Combo1, 'Salary' should be filtered out from combo2 and 3 (It should not display 'Salary' option)

I am doing following code on change listener of combo1-

```
listeners: {
        change: function(combo, record, index) { 
          var combo1Val = combo.value; // Give the selected value correctly
          this.filterCombo(combo1Val , combo2);
          this.filterCombo(combo1Val , combo3);
        }
 }
```

and this is function body

```
filterCombo: function (combo1Val , combo) {
      if (combo1Val  ==  'Student') {
         combo.store.filterBy(function (record) {
              return record.get('text') != 'Salary';
         });
      }
      else {
         combo.store.clearFilter();
      }
}
```

The problem here is for first time when I select Student from combo1, 'Salary' option disappears from combo2. Then, when I expand combo3, it displays salary option there, and again whwn I click on combo2, again it displays 'salary' option. somehow this filter is not working.

Can anybody tell what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: not sure about 2.3. if available use before expand clear and filter the store.

Comment: try fiddle definitely i will help you solve this

Answer (score 1):

you can try this in combo2

```
listeners: {
    expand: function(combo) {
        combo.store.clearFilter();
        if (combo1Val  ==  'Student') {
            //filter
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help :) why still in 2.3

Comment: Will upgrade soon :) I have posted my problem and the answer. Good solution though !! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Though the answer provided by raghavendra is correct and works well but in the scenario if there are many combos(more than two) that need to be filtered, we have to write expand listener for each combo.

So thought of writing the code in one place that is in combo1 change event. 
The problem was somehow after entering the function it was going into else statement i.e. `combo.store.clearFilter();` so clearing out the filter.
I have solved my problem by checking the condition in combo1 change event itself instead of inside the function for each combo.

```
listeners: {
     change: function(combo, record, index) { 
          var combo1Val = combo.value; // Give the selected value correctly
          if (combo1Val  ==  'Student') {
              this.filterCombo(combo1Val , combo2);
              this.filterCombo(combo1Val , combo3);
          }
          else {
              combo2.store.clearFilter();
              combo3.store.clearFilter();
          }
     }
}

filterCombo: function (combo1Val , combo) {         
         combo.store.filterBy(function (record) {
              return record.get('text') != 'Salary';
         });
}
```